# How do I get the bouncing ball to wrap around the x-axis

Tags: python, tkinter

I cannot figure out how to get the ball to wrap around the screen.  I have tried setting the x1 and x2 values to zero and this did not work.  My present example is showing that I am attempting to use `canvas.move()` to move the position of the ball to x value 0 and this is not working as well.  The goal is to keep the height as `velocity_y` so that it looks as if it is continuous.  If anyone has any solutions that would be a great help, thanks!

```
import tkinter as Tkinter 

#####
# Create root window 
####
root = Tkinter.Tk()

#####
# Create Model
######
speed_intvar = Tkinter.IntVar()
speed_intvar.set(3) # Initialize y coordinate
# radius and x-coordinate of circle
r = 10
x = 150
y = 150
direction = 0.5 # radians of angle in standard position, ccw from positive x axis

######
# Create Controller
#######
# Instantiate and place slider
speed_slider = Tkinter.Scale(root, from_=5, to=1, variable=speed_intvar,    
                              label='speed')
speed_slider.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=Tkinter.W)
# Create and place directions for the user
text = Tkinter.Label(root, text='Drag slider \nto adjust\nspeed.')
text.grid(row=0, column =0)

######
# Create View
#######
# Create and place a canvas
canvas = Tkinter.Canvas(root, width=600, height=600, background='#FFFFFF')
canvas.grid(row=0, rowspan=2, column=1)

# Create a circle on the canvas to match the initial model
circle_item = canvas.create_oval(x-r, y-r, x+r, y+r, 
                                 outline='#000000', fill='#00FFFF')
import math
def animate():
    global direction
    # Get the slider data and create x- and y-components of velocity
    velocity_x = speed_intvar.get() * math.cos(direction) # adj = hyp*cos()
    velocity_y = speed_intvar.get() * math.sin(direction) # opp = hyp*sin()
    # Change the canvas item's coordinates
    canvas.move(circle_item, velocity_x, velocity_y)

    # Get the new coordinates and act accordingly if ball is at an edge
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = canvas.coords(circle_item)

    # If crossing left or right of canvas
    if x2>canvas.winfo_width() or x1 <0: 
        # direction = math.pi - direction # Reverse the x-component of velocity
        canvas.move(circle_item, x2, canvas.winfo_height())
    # If crossing top or bottom of canvas
    if y2>canvas.winfo_height() or y1<0: 
        direction = -1 * direction # Reverse the y-component of velocity

    # Create an event in 1 msec that will be handled by animate(),
    # causing recursion        
    canvas.after(1, animate)
# Call function directly to start the recursion
animate()

#######
# Event Loop
#######
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [tkinter bouncing ball](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59988214/tkinter-bouncing-ball)

Comment: I think a simple if statement would do the trick. Just check if ball location is outside of the wall and then set location to start of other wall. @ZarakiKenpachi Good name choice :D

Comment: @Mike-SMT Thanks!  I'll give it a try

Comment: If you want to wrap the ball to the left side of canvas when it reaches right side of canvas, try changing `canvas.move(circle_item, x2, canvas.winfo_height())` to `canvas.move(circle_item, -x1, 0)`.